# Data check during insertion in table

Tags: oracle

I want to Check the value of data Before insertion in a table.Like ,if things like " or  & come in the data,it should ignore it or insert using some escape sequence .

```
create table test (checkit varchar2(40));
insert into test values("Here is the & test data");
```

or

```
insert into test values("Here is the " test data");
```

Is there a way to do that in oracle?
thanks

EDIT

I want to know the solution especially for Characters like & , " etc not for normal data as shown in the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using [BEFORE trigger](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_triggers.htm).

---

Here is an example replacing & with `&amp;` and " with `&quot`;

```
SET DEFINE OFF;
drop table test;
create table test (checkit varchar2(60));


CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER validateTest
  BEFORE DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE ON test
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  :new.checkit := replace(:new.checkit, '&', '&lte;');
  :new.checkit := replace(:new.checkit, '"', '&quot;');
END;
/

insert into test (checkit) values ('Here is the & test "data"');
select * from test;
```

Output:

```
drop table test succeeded.
create table succeeded.
TRIGGER validateTest Compiled.
1 rows inserted
CHECKIT                                                      
------------------------------------------------------------ 
Here is the &lte; test &quot;data&quot;                    

1 rows selected
```

Obviously replacement strings can be whatever.

Comment: can u give an example how to check data value using before trigger?

Comment: This answetr is at best too cursory to be helpful and quite possibly wrong.  Please justify it with a worked example.